# How to connect to remote mySQL DB in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I'm using Yii 2.0 basic template. I have tried to connect to the DB. The connection in local db is working. But I'm not able to connect to the remote mySQL db that is in domain server.

This is my db config:

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=smargav.com;dbname=smargavc_Konnections',
    'username' => 'smargavc_Konnect',
    'password' => '******',
    'charset' => 'utf8'
];
```

I'm getting error as following:

> {"name":"Database Exception","message":"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user 'smargavc_Konnect'@'122.167.47.26' (using password:

Answer (score 1):

connection string seems fine

Several possible causes :

1. smargavc_Konnect user doesn't have permission to connect remotely
2. MYSQL is in stopped state at remote server
3. 3306 port is not allowed in remote server
4. Your IP is not allowed to access the remote server using http

Check if all of these are true , you should be able to connect

Comment: How can i figure out these problems?

Comment: try connecting using any mysql client using mysql workbench , If you are : that means all these 4 problems have fixed.

Comment: For problem 1 : login to mysql using root check user table and it's access
for Problem 2: login to server start mysql by sudo service mysqld start
For problem 3: check if port 3306 is allowed in security group

Comment: This time, i uploaded yii framework  into server. now im getting 500 error. Please check   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340469/how-to-solve-500-error-on-yii-db-connection