# How to solve 500 Error on Yii Db connection

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have uploaded yii framework into my server.
i'm using string for connecting db is

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=smargavc_Konnections',
    'username' => 'smargavc_Konnect',
    'password' => '******',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Here, Wheather dont know db is connected or not.

When i trying in postman to access the rest call, getting 500 errro

Comment: it has nothing to with DB check your htaccess file.

Comment: Please check your logs, see what error is being logged there... This is basic PHP debugging knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

500 Error is for CODE error. Not connection error.

To check connection you can simply go,

```
print_r(Yii::app()->db); // Yii 1.1.x framework
```

Regards

Comment: Even index page also not opening. But my whole path is correct

Comment: Hope you have made runtime writable? then try to run some basic checklist for Yii setup as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the db connection then use `getIsActive()` method of yii\db\Connection Class. For more info check this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html#getIsActive%28%29-detail)

Answer (score 0):

I had response configuration in web.php. It made problem of 500 Error.

```
 'response' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\Response',
            'on beforeSend' => function ($event) {
                $response = $event->sender;
                if ($response->data !== null && !empty(Yii::$app->request->get('suppress_response_code'))) {
                    $response->data = [
                        'success' => $response->isSuccessful,
                        'data' => $response->data,
                    ];
                    $response->statusCode = 200;
                }
            },
        ],
```

I had this in my configuration. I dont know the reason. But it solve my issue